# How to execute ccm cqlsh commands like INSERT ,CREATE and SEELCT inside shell script?

Tags: shell, makefile, cassandra, cqlsh, ccm

Wanted to execute few commands independently like CREATE, INSERT and SELECT inside shell script i.e., makefile.sh.
Example:-

```
cqlsh "CREATE <SOME QUERY>;"
cqlsh "INSERT <SOME QUERY>;"
cqlsh "SELECT <SOME QUERY>;"
```

Is there any way to do so??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-e` option and specify a cql statement or `-f` and specify a file. More details [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html).